# notepad++ changing a URL

Tags: notepad++

The syntax to manually download an image on a website I use is for example:

https://www.newspapers.com/download/image/?type=jpg&id=999

However, I have a bunch of URL's which are in the wrong layout such as:

https://www.newspapers.com/image/999/?terms=randomletters or https://www.newspapers.com/image/999/?terms=randomnumbers

How do I make notepad++ remove everything after the image id (in this example 999) and also restructure the URL to the correct syntax as in the first example?

Comment: Please, don't crosspost: https://superuser.com/q/1322907/763386

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl`+`h`

Search Mode: Regular expression

Find: `^https://www.newspapers.com/image/([0-9]+)/\?terms=.+`

Replace: `https://www.newspapers.com/download/image/?type=jpg&id=$1`

Comment: Why are you escaping the slashes (all but one)?

Comment: You're right @Toto this isn't needed - force of habit. Have updated my answer.